# User name while creating new scratch org

Tags: scratch-org

How to set username for the scratch org when you create it?
When I create a scratch org using command `sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a ebikes`
I was able to get the scratch org Id along with different user name instead of different user name I want my user name to be set.

How is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use an existing user name from an existing Salesforce org?

Comment: No. I when I give the above command I want new scratch org to be created but with the user name I need.But When I give the above command new scratch org is created but with the random user  name and is redirected to some other salesforce account , it is not mine actually.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that this is not possible.

If you need a specifically named user, create that user after the scratch org has been created.

Adding `--json` to `sfdx force:org:create` returns a JSON object with the username field in the `username` property if your problem is just that you need the name in later logic.

Comment: actually when I push source into that newly generated scratch org, its taking me to different salesforce account (url) which I dont need.I am new to Salesforce.I am working on Lightning web component basics(push and deploy web component files)

Comment: I not only need name I specify, I need my account to be opened when I give sfdx:org:open. It should be redirected to my account.

Comment: That's just not how scratch orgs work. If you want to use a Developer or Sandbox org, then you authenticate to that with the JWT or Web auth methods and then use `force:source: deploy` & `force:source:retrieve` to move the metadata in and out.